# Профессоров или профессор?

Tags: склонение

Если мы указываем количество профессоров, то какую форму этого слова надо употребить?

*141 профессор* или *141 профессоров*?

Answer (score 4):

Количественное составное числительное, оканчивающееся на *один,* в составе подлежащего предполагает сказуемое в форме единственного числа мужского, женского или среднего рода: *Двадцать один вагон отправлен. Тридцать одна тонна зерна отгружена.*

[Источник](http://ebooks.grsu.by/ruslang/trudnosti-soglasovaniya-imen-chislitelnykh.htm)

Как видим, ***вагон*** и ***тонна*** стоят в единственном числе.